# In Perl, how do I put multiple packages in a single .pm file?

Tags: perl, oop, perl-module

I'm pretty sure that I read somewhere that it's possible, but there are a few gotchas that you need to be aware of. Unfortunately, I can't find the tutorial or page that described what you need to do. I looked through the [Perl tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html), and didn't find the one that I remember reading. Could someone point me to a page or document that describes how to put multiple packages into a single .pm file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You simply start off the new package with another package statement:

```
package PackageOne;

# ...... code

package PackageTwo;

# .... more code
```

[Problems with this approach](http://oreilly.com/catalog/prkunix/excerpt/PWPMch01.html#MARKER-9-23) ([archived on 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090417065554/http://oreilly.com/catalog/prkunix/excerpt/PWPMch01.html))

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the article that I read, there were a few other things that you had to do or problems that might appear with scoping.

Comment: of course there will be scoping problems and thats why its not recommended,  See the link I added.

Comment: You can only `use` a package with a name that corresponds to the filename, and you can only (easily) `use` a file that contains a package corresponding to its name. Other than that and the fact that file-scoped lexicals will "leak" into the next package (avoidable by adding braces) there isn't a lot to know.

Comment: The problems link is dead

Comment: You can access that link through the "archives": https://web.archive.org/web/20090417065554/http://oreilly.com/catalog/prkunix/excerpt/PWPMch01.html

Comment: What about exports, imports and `@ISA`?

Answer (score 42):

This is how I normally do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

{
    package A;
    sub new   { my $class = shift; bless \$class => $class }
    sub hello { say 'hello from A' }
}

{
    package B;
    use Data::Dumper;
    sub new   { my $class = shift; bless { @_ } => $class }
    sub hello { say 'Hello from B + ' . shift->dump       }
    sub dump  { Dumper $_[0] }
}

$_->hello for A->new, B->new( foo => 'bar' );
```

Comment: What is the block scope good for if the package defines already its own scope?

Comment: @ceving - For the same reason that `package` was changed at perl 5.14 to now allow the following syntax:  `package A { ... }`.   NB. This is the same as `{ package A; ... }`).   This avoid *gotchas* you may get with things like `my` & `our`.  ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/functions/package.html

Comment: What about exports, imports and inheritance?

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
   package A;
   use Exporter;
   our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
   our @EXPORT_OK = qw(a_sub);
   our @EXPORT = qw(a_sub);

   sub a_sub {
       # your code ...
   }
}
{
   package B;
   use Exporter;
   our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
   our @EXPORT_OK = qw(b_sub);
   our @EXPORT = qw(b_sub);

   sub b_sub {
       # your code ...
   }
}

# Main code starts here ##############

use boolean;
use Data::Dumper;

import A qw(a_sub);
import B qw(b_sub);

a_sub();
b_sub();
```

The important point is that instead of using "use", you change it for "import" (that way it won't go and try to look for the file).

Comment: My approach was similar, I just changed `{ package A; ... }` to `package A { ... }`.

Comment: Very good point about `use`.  The same is true for `require`.  If you need to `use` or `require` package `A`, set `$INC{'A.pm'}=1` before the `use` or `require`.  That tells perl the module is already loaded, and it doesn't need to look on disk.  For `use`, that assignment will need to be in a `BEGIN` block, e.g., `BEGIN { $INC{'A.pm'}=1; }`.

Comment: Is it possible to import a constant (`use constant`) that way? With `use strict` I'm seeing `Can't use bareword ...`.

Comment: @U.Windl : it would be good if you ask that question (own post) with an example of what are you trying to do and link this question or answer for reference.

Comment: @lepe: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046430/how-to-import-a-constant-with-use-strict-avoiding-cant-use-bareword-as?noredirect=1#comment96861990_55046430

Answer (score 3):

How to do it: just issue multiple `package` instructions.

Gotchas I can think of: `my`-variables aren't package-localized, so they're shared anyway.  Before you issue any, you're in package `main` by default.

Comment: You can't use `use package` when you just use the `package` keyword.

Comment: Well you can't have it all, can you? :)