# How to import a constant with "use strict", avoiding "Can't use bareword ... as an ARRAY ref"

Tags: perl, import, module, reference, constants

I have a module in a file that exports a constant that is an array reference. I can use that constant inside its defining module, but I cannot use it after importing it.  The error message says `Can't use bareword ("AR") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at mod.pl line 28.`.

Consider this demo code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require 5.018_000;

use warnings;
use strict;

package Test;

use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
    require Exporter;
    our $VERSION = 1.00;                # for version checking
    # Inherit from Exporter to export functions and variables
    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT = qw();                 # exported by default
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw(AR);            # can be optionally exported
}

use constant AR => [1,2,3];

print AR->[1], "\n";
1;

package main;
Test->import(qw(AR));
print AR->[1], "\n";
#Can't use bareword ("AR") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at mod.pl line 28.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @zdim: It's exactly the code presented in `man perlmod(1)`.

Comment: ugh, you are right ... somebody should edit that, to not confuse people.  It's a discussion with a point, no question, and that had been of practical relevance (20 years ago?), but that's not how we set up a module.  See [Exporter](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for a much simpler and clearer info (boilerplate) for that.  And many SO posts of course, starting with ikegami's answer here

Comment: @zdim I've opened a perlbug with a patch: https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=133909

Comment: @Grinnz Great, thank you. I looked over that part again, and it is indeed offered as a simple and practical overview of a module (so to speak). It should really be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute the `import` before a reference to the constant is compiled.

You could use yet another `BEGIN` block to do that, but that means we have now two hacks. Rather than frankensteining both the module's user and the module itself, I suggest the following approach. It keeps the inlined package looking as much as a real module as possible.

The approach consists of the following:

1. Place the entire module as-is in a `BEGIN` block at the start of the script.
2. Replace the trailing `1;` with `$INC{"Foo/Bar.pm"} = 1;` (for `Foo::Bar`).

That's it. This allows you to `use` the module as normal.

So if your module is the following:

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our $VERSION = 1.00;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(AR);

use constant AR => [1,2,3];

1;
```

And if your script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.018;
use warnings;

use Test qw( AR );

say AR->[1];
```

You can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN {
    package Test;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use Exporter qw( import );

    our $VERSION = 1.00;
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw(AR);

    use constant AR => [1,2,3];

    $INC{__PACKAGE__ .'.pm'} = 1;  # Tell Perl the module is already loaded.
}

use 5.018;
use warnings;

use Test qw( AR );

say AR->[1];
```

---

As you can see, I've made some cleanups. Specifically,

- If you're going to requires 5.18, might as well enable the language features it provides. This was done by replacing `required 5.018;` with `use 5.018;`

  - We don't need to use `use strict;` explicitly because `use 5.012;` and higher enable strictures.
  - We can use `say` because `use 5.010;` enables it.
- A Test is not an Exporter, so it shouldn't inherit from Exporter. For the last 15-20 years, Exporter has been providing a better interface than the one you used.
- No need to create or initialize `@EXPORT` if you don't need it.
- No need for a `BEGIN` block around the initialization of `@ISA` and `@EXPORT_OK`.

Comment: So the real trick is `$INC{"Test.pm"} = 1` and using a normal `use Test`? May I ask what does not work with my code? Also, it it possible to make `"test.pm"` independent of the actual file name being used?

Comment: No, I clearly listed two steps to "the trick", and that's only one of them. /// The name of the key in `%INC` in based on the package's name (i.e. based on the name the module world have), not the script's name.

Comment: @U.Windl The reason your code did not work as you expect is specifically because you are defining the module in the same file as you are using it, and at compile time (when you want to import the symbols to use for later) the module has thus not been run yet, and neither has your `import` call. If you keep modules in separate files, everything will work normally because the module will be compiled, run, and imported from in your script's compile phase by the `use` statement - your manual `import` on the other hand happens at runtime.

Comment: @Grinnz: I still have a problem with understanding: I thought that `use constant ...` is evaluated at compile time. I understand that the exporter stuff and the `$INC{"Test.pm"} = 1` has to be inside a `BEGIN` block, but why all the rest?

Comment: It's just a lot shorter, simpler and cleaner to just wrap the whole module in a BEGIN block. It's also closer to the normal way of loading a module. Yes, you could use a normal block instead of a BEGIN block, and use multiple BEGIN blocks within (as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/7YR1xC9g)), but that's longer, and far more complicated, error-prone and messy. It also requires more indenting and more typing. There's simply no reason to do it that way.

Comment: I just made a small improvement to your answer, but actually I felt like reducing the answer to it's essence: "Fake module load using `$INC{__MODULE__ . '.pm'} = 1`; then you can use the module the normal way."

Comment: I believe you mean `$INC{__PACKAGE__ . '.pm'} = 1;`. But that doesn't work (in general). You actually need `( my $mod_path = __PACKAGE__ ) =~ s{::}{/}g; $mod_path .= ".pm"; $INC{$mod_path} = 1;`. Given the complexity, the little bit of redundancy is rather paletable.

Comment: You could use `module_notional_filename(__PACKAGE__)` from [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime#module_notional_filename(NAME)) to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: @U.Windl It's also not just that certain parts of the module have to be in a BEGIN block; the `import` of the module also has to happen at compile time. `use` accomplishes this, thus tricking `use` into thinking the module is already loaded is a clean solution; alternatively, you can call the import method in a BEGIN block.

Answer (score 3):

The `print AR->[1]` statement is parsed during compile time but the constant `AR` isn't imported into the `main` namespace until runtime.

The fix is to make sure that `AR` gets imported into `main` at compile-time

```
BEGIN { Test->import( qw(AR) ) }
```

There are also run-time workarounds

```
print &AR->[1], "\n";
print AR()->[1], "\n";
```

Comment: That doesn't work in Perl 5.20 I get a `Undefined subroutine &main::AR` error message when using the AR() method you suggest

Comment: Odd, I'm on Perl 5.20.2 and it defiantly fails, which is why I added my answer. I guess someone fixed a bug between our two versions

Comment: All three solutions work fine in 5.20. In fact, they work fine in all versions from 5.6 to present (5.28) if you remove `require 5.018_000;`.

Comment: @ikegami: Want to comment on `require 5.018_000`? I thought it enables language feature up to Perl 5.18 (which is the version I had been using).

Comment: It just ensures the interpreter version is 5.18+. Totally unneeded for your program

Comment: Another "runtime workaround" would be `Test::AR->[1]`

Comment: @Grinnz: Wouldn't that work even without any import?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, thus it does not rely on whether the import happens at compile time

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
BEGIN {
    require Exporter;
    our $VERSION = 1.00;                # for version checking
    # Inherit from Exporter to export functions and variables
    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT = qw();                 # exported by default
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw(AR);            # can be optionally exported
}
```

to

```
# Inherit from Exporter to export functions and variables
use parent 'Exporter';
our $VERSION = 1.00;                # for version checking
our @EXPORT = qw();                 # exported by default
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(AR);            # can be optionally exported
```

and your code now works

I suspect that there is some code in Exporter that has to be run before you set up your `@EXPORT_OK` variable

Comment: This change doesn't help at all.